# Print Keys With 5 Highest Values

Tags: java

I have a HashMap that is defined as:

```
Map<String, Double> data = new HashMap<String, Double>();
```

and I am trying to print out the 5 Strings with the highest Double values. I try doing that by running a for each loop 5 times and saving the highest value while I iterate the whole HashMap 5 times over but I am getting null pointer exception errors at the if statement.

```
int highest = 0;
String highestkey;

 for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
     for(Map.Entry<String, Double> x : data.entrySet()){
        if(data.get(x) > highest){
           highestkey = x.getKey();
        }
     }
     System.out.println(highestkey);
     info_words.remove(highestkey);
  }
```

What my code should be doing is keeping track of the highest Double value as it parses the HashMap and then will end up printing the highest key then removing it so there is no duplicate, then repeating the process 4 more times but It is not working as intended

Answer (score 0):

The NPE is because you are not accessing the `Map` with an existing key.

Instead of `ata.get(x) > highest` it should be `ata.get(x.getKey()) > highest`.

But also, `highest` should be a `Double` instead of an `int`.

And `highestkey` has to be initialized, for example:

```
String highestkey = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```java
        Double highest = 0.0;
        String highestkey = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for (Map.Entry<String, Double> x : data.entrySet()) {
                if (x.getValue() > highest) {
                    highest = x.getValue();
                    highestkey = x.getKey();
                }
            }
            System.out.println(highestkey);
            //remove highest here
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler method would be to sort the entries and take the first 5:

```
data.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue().reversed())
    .limit(5).map(Map.Entry::getKey).forEach(System.out::println);
```